# how can I convert tensor shape to numpy array?

Tags: deep-learning, data-mining, data

This is what my data looks like:
[image]

I want it to be numpy array, instead of a tensor, so that i can convert it to a dataframe. Is there a way to do so?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are pytorch tensors, you can convert them to numpy arrays using the [`.numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html) method. Depending on whether your tensors are stored on the GPU or still attached to the graph you might have to add `.cpu()` and [`.detach()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html).

Comment: They are indeed pytorch tensors, and i did run my code in GPU. When i add .detach() i get the error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'detach'. When I add .cpu() I get 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cpu'.. Either way, thanks for your help!

Comment: I solved the problem above by selecting the first part of the tensor tuple with [0] and second part [1]. So thanks !

Comment: Indeed, `encoded_data_T1` is a tuple containing two tensors, so if you want to convert them both you can either use normal indexing or use a generator expression (very useful if your tuple contains a larger number of items).